# How to pass a Request.Querystring as a parameter to a stored procedure via asp:SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a stored procedure that needs a case file ID to find and return data I need. I have a drop down list that has an `asp:SqlDataSource` that makes a call to the stored procedure. But I don't know/unsure of how I can pass a querystring to the `<SelectParameters>` of the SqlDataSource. In my code behind I can query the case file ID with `Request.QueryString["fileID"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add an element of QueryStringParameter to the SelectParameters collection of the SqlDataSource.

```
 <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="fileID" QueryStringField="fileID" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I just read this on the msdn website and did that. However on a side note, is there a possibility of putting in an if statement for the query string? so say if:person is doing action a, make the QueryStringField="stringA", else QueryStringField="stringB"?